# Split Column by comma and then adding it back onto the original column associated with the email

Tags: google-sheets

Dataset:
Each customer has an email account with us. Each email account can have multiple in-app accounts associated to the email.

**Sample Dataset:**

| account_id | customer_email |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2] | junglehouse1@yahoo.com |
| [23,68] | nycdeepms23@me.com |
| [10,5] | azn34girl@gmail.com |
| [123,4] | syeedygonzalez@gmail.com |
| 129 | fight-me@hotmail.com |
| 126 | azulescielos@gmail.com |
| 34 | bakahbkah@gmail.com |
| [68,4] | finale341040@gmail.com |

**Ideal Output:**

| account_id | customer_email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | junglehouse1@yahoo.com |
| 2 | junglehouse1@yahoo.com |
| 23 | nycdeepms23@me.com |
| 68 | nycdeepms23@me.com |
| 10 | azn34girl@gmail.com |
| 5 | azn34girl@gmail.com |
| 123 | syeedygonzalez@gmail.com |
| 4 | syeedygonzalez@gmail.com |
| 129 | fight-me@hotmail.com |
| 126 | azulescielos@gmail.com |
| 34 | bakahbkah@gmail.com |
| 68 | finale341040@gmail.com |
| 4 | finale341040@gmail.com |

Steps I am currently working on:

Step 1) I removed the brackets from the pizza_topping_id. I then split the account_id with the Data > Split Text to Columns in Google Sheets.

Now I'm stuck with a dataset with multiple columns for account_id. My question is: How can I add it back and also have the associated customer_email with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing this you can use reduce, that let's you stack the different values. With the help of REGEXREPLACE you can remove the square-brackets, and BYROW, TRANSPOSE and SPLIT combine to work with each id as one different row:

```
    =REDUCE(A1:B1,A2:A,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="",a,
VSTACK(a,BYROW(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(v),"\[|\]",""),",")),LAMBDA(each,{each,OFFSET(v,0,1)}))))))
```

[image]